# Why are iterators private?

Tags: java, iterator

Iterators are nested classes exported to clients. Then why are the declared private instead of public ?
eg:

`private abstract class HashIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {`

```
 private final class EntryIterator extends HashIterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
        public Map.Entry<K,V> next() {
            return nextEntry();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, they don't have to be private; i.e. if you are designing a data structure, there is nothing stopping you from declaring your iterator class as `public`.

However, private iterators are "good design" if the data structure is intended to be a string abstraction; i.e. one where the internal representation is hidden from client code.

One reason is that making the iterator class private prevents undesirable coupling; i.e. it stops some external class from depending on the actual iterator code in a way that would make future code changes harder.

Another reason is that in most cases an extensible public iterator class couldn't be instantiated anyway.  Or at least, not without relaxing the abstraction boundary of the data structure.

---

Another way to look at this is that making the iterator class `public` would not achieve anything.  The caller typically doesn't need to use anything apart from the methods in the `Iterator` API.  And if it does, then the solution is to extend the iterator API (interface) to provide the additional methods.

Comment: It means a private nested class can also be exported ?

Comment: I thought a private nested class was useful only to the outer class and no other class. But clients can access and use it.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper - An instance of a private class that implements a public interface can be used by other classes ... if they are provided with a reference to the instance.  I still don't get your point.

Comment: `An instance of a private class that implements a public interface can be used by other classes`  -- I was not aware of this. This is what confused me, and you helped me out.

Answer (score 3):

It hides implementation details which class users dont need to know. Eg HashSet

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() 

Returns an iterator over the elements in this set.
```

it does not say which concrete Iterator is returned, it is a private class invisible for users, users dont need to know implementation details and HashSet designers are free to change the implementation without notice

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons and caveats to it:

- Keeping  class `private` would not allow client to depend on the actual implementation
- Keeps the code *loosely coupled*
- It strictly applies *code to an `interface`* as it will not allow you to cast to actual implementation because of it being `private`
- It logically emphasizes that the `class` is only useful to the `parent class` and no other code should depend on that
- Actual implementation can change anytime without notice from Java team as already stated in other answer.